# In rake task, execute command, read stdout until a certain line is matched, then detach and continue task

Tags: ruby, process, io, rake, stdout

I want to launch a java servlet, observe its stdout until I see that it has fully loaded, and then go back to the rest of my rake task while keeping that process running. Currently I have something like this:

```
IO.popen "java -jar ./tools/tests/servlet.jar" do |io|
  io.each do |line|
    puts line
    Process.detach(io.pid) if line.include? 'Server ready.' # need help here
  end
end

puts "Ready..."
```

How do I exit this IO block to continue with the task, while keeping the process running? Thank you!

**Edit: Temporary Bad Solution**

```
def with_server_running
  IO.popen "java -jar ./tools/tests/servlet.jar" do |io|
    io.each do |line|
      puts line
      yield if line.include? 'Server ready.'
    end
  end
end

with_server_running do
  puts "Ready..."
  # rest of task
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
if(line.include? 'Server ready.')
  Process.detach(io.pid)
  exit(0)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Linuxios, but that still leaves me in the process. When I ctrl+c to terminate the server my task continues on as it should, but I need it to happen without ctrl+c. I could append & to have the server run in the background and read the io until I get what I'm looking for but surely there's a better way?

Comment: Alas, still stuck in the process, except `SIGINT` is now no longer followed up by the rest of the task. At least `break` would continue the task after `SIGINT`.

Comment: I think for now I'll just send it into the background and call the rest of my task from inside that conditional. But really not a great solution. If anyone else has a better solution please do let me know!

Comment: @glortho: Wait. Explain the problem to me again. Which process did it leave you in?

Comment: The servlet process holds up anything else after the IO block. For now I've decided just to yield a passed-in block inside the IO block (after running the servlet in the background), and it's fine, but ultimately I would rather detach from that process, keep track of it by pid, and return to it later.